# Interpretation of market condition given by relation between elasticities

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, supply-and-demand, price-theory

The total market demand is given by the sum of the two destinations ($e$ and $f$) given to the product.

Given these conditions:

- Demand: $d(p) = e(p) + f(p)$ where:

  - $d(p) > 0$, $d'(p) \leq 0$;
  - $e(p) > 0$, $e'(p) \leq 0$;
  - $f(p) > 0$, $f'(p) \leq 0$;
- Supply: $s(p)$ where $s(p) > 0$ and $s'(p) \geq 0$;
- Equilibrium: $d(p) = s(p)$;

**How can the condition below be interpreted?**

- $\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}-\frac{d'(p)}{d(p)}> \frac{e(p)}{f(p)}\frac{s'(p)}{s(p)}$

It may be helpfull to see that's possible to multiply by $p$ and get some elasticities:

$p*\big(\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}-\frac{d'(p)}{d(p)}> \frac{e(p)}{f(p)}\frac{s'(p)}{s(p)}\big) \Rightarrow$
$\varepsilon_{f}-\varepsilon_{d} > \frac{e(p)}{f(p)}\varepsilon_{s}$

This is a simplification of the whole situation from the The Ethanol-subsidy Multiplier  [example](http://models.economicreasoning.com/EthanolSubsidyMultiplier.pdf) (or [notebook file](http://models.economicreasoning.com/EthanolSubsidyMultiplier.nb)).

Comment: Well i dont see how you postulate d(p)=s(p) with d(p)<0 and s(p)>0.

Comment: Indeed, @Armenthus. There was was a typo, although that relation was still possible (at least for a p*).